where to get an adapter for PEX-B insert-style fitting for both the PEX-A and PEX-B pipes
I am a DIYer and getting ready to run 1/2" Pex A throughtout my new house. The slab contractor stubbed in 3/4" Pex B. How do I convert?

You'd get better flow with the 3/4, only stepping down to 1/2 after the shutoff valve of each fixture.  I.e. it makes sense to run 1/2 to the fixtures, because that's the standard size for the fixture pipes.  The travel pipes can be 3/4, which will retard flow less.  This makes particular sense for the supply to the water heater, which probably takes and supplies 3/4 anyway.
If you do it that way, you can just buy shutoff valves that are 3/4 on one side and 1/2 on the other side.
If you prefer not to have a shutoff valve at that point, you can also buy converters (same kind of brass piece as the shutoff valve, only without the shutoff).  I had no trouble finding them on the Home Depot site, so I would expect them to be easily available at any plumbing supply store.  You can even get manifolds that have a 3/4 inlet and 1/2 outlets.
Pipes that carry heated water may cause more waste at 3/4 than 1/2 because you need to pump out the cooled water to get to the heated water.  Recirculation pumps can fix the water waste but may cause energy waste (if they run all the time rather than just when hot water is needed).  That said, the hot water will likely come out of the heater at 3/4.  When you step it down is up to you.  You have to balance waste vs. flow.  3/4 will better support two fixtures at once.  For that reason, you may want to support it at least to the first manifold (split) after the water heater.
For a hot water pipe that sees frequent use, insulation may help preserve the heat between uses and reduce the waste.  However, if you only use a pipe infrequently (e.g. a washer), then that won't matter.
There are fittings that are specific to Pex-A or Pex-B, but some are compatible with both.  You should be able to just order what you need at any plumbing supply store.  Just be sure to mention the oddities (things that need both A and B; or 3/4 and 1/2).

Good answer, all true, but remember that waiting for hot water to arrive at a faucet or shower head with 3/4 travel pipes will waste more than twice the water (and time) as 1/2 will due to the greater volume of water in 3/4. If the OP is in a water conservation area, it's a consideration. Adding a hot water circulating pump can eliminate the waste, but at the cost of higher energy bills.
